# append ContextMenu to Silverlight Image Control in Runtime

Tags: image, silverlight, runtime, contextmenu

I'm trying to do these in runtime in my silverlight application:

1- create a list of images
2- define a custom ContextMenu for any of them
My code in as Below:

```
void AddImageViewerToGridCells(Grid g)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= g.RowDefinitions.Count; i++)
            for (int j = 1; j <= g.ColumnDefinitions.Count; j++)
            {
                var b = new Image();
                b.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"Drop.jpg", UriKind.Relative));
                b.SetValue(Image.NameProperty, "img" + i.ToString() + "_" + j.ToString());                    
                b.Stretch = Stretch.Fill;
                b.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, i-1);
                b.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, j-1);
                b.MouseRightButtonDown += b_MouseRightButtonDown;
                g.Children.Add(b);
            }
    }

void b_MouseRightButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        Image img = (Image)sender;
        ContextMenu cm = new ContextMenu();
        MenuItem mi1 = new MenuItem();
        mi1.Header = "Add To List";
        mi1.Click += mi1_Click;
        cm.Items.Add(mi1);
        MenuItem mi2 = new MenuItem();
        mi2.Header = "Remove From List";
        cm.Items.Add(mi2);
        ContextMenuService.SetContextMenu(img, cm);
    }
```

Bu I can't see my ContextMenu.
As I know I should deliver a dependencyObject To SetContextMenu Method, But (just as I guess)  my runtime control is not a dependency Object.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

thanks for Not Responding me! 
the solution is as below:

```
void AddImageViewerToGridCells(Grid g)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= g.RowDefinitions.Count; i++)
            for (int j = 1; j <= g.ColumnDefinitions.Count; j++)
            {
                var b = new Image();
                b.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"Drop.jpg", UriKind.Relative));
                b.SetValue(Image.NameProperty, "img" + i.ToString() + "_" + j.ToString());                    
                b.Stretch = Stretch.Fill;
                b.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, i-1);
                b.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, j-1);
                ContextMenu cm = new ContextMenu();
                ContextMenuService.SetContextMenu(b, cm);
                cm.Opened+=cm_Opened;
                //b.MouseRightButtonDown += b_MouseRightButtonDown;
                g.Children.Add(b);                    
            }
    }

    void cm_Opened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ContextMenu cm = (ContextMenu)sender;
        cm.Items.Clear();
        MenuItem mi1 = new MenuItem();
        mi1.Header = "Add To List" + DateTime.Now.ToString();
        mi1.Click += mi1_Click;
        cm.Items.Add(mi1);
        MenuItem mi2 = new MenuItem();
        mi2.Header = "Remove From List" + DateTime.Now.ToString();
        cm.Items.Add(mi2);
    }
```